# set background-color property to entire document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to set the background-color property to entire body, but my code seems not working
I am learning jquery, but still I a newbie

I am using the selector this for call the
 body element and apply to it a style

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
           $(this).css("background-color","green");
         }    
        );

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="destinations">
           <li>First</li>
           <li>Second</li>
           <li>Third</li>
           <li>Fourth</li>
           <li>Fifth</li>
           <li class="six">Sixth</li>
        </ul>
        <p>This is another parragraph</p>
        <p>and this is another more</p>
    </body>
    </html

>
```

Comment: I understand that you're learning jQuery, but if you want to set the background of body, better do it using CSS. Learn jQuery by doing things for which jQuery is *actually* required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery, $(this) refers to the DOM element that invokes the current function. Since you are calling $(this) in the document 'ready' event, $(this) refers the document (DOM), which is the reason why your code doesn't work.

To apply the CSS rule, you'll have to target the body tag instead. Therefore, you'll have to change this:

`$(this).css("background-color","green");`

to that:

`$('body').css("background-color","green");`

Comment: its better to add some explanation as well.. as to why's the code posted in question is not working.. :)

Comment: You're right. Added a brief explanation why the original code didn't work. Feel free to suggest any further editing.

Comment: Not sure what you even mean by " DOM element". There is no `<DOM>` element as far as I know.

Comment: The first time I mention it, the DOM element is the element in the DOM that invokes the function. The second time it was a monkey typing error. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You should select the body and set the background there

```
$('body').css("background-color","green");
```

Comment: Thanks friend. I thought that it was (this)

Answer (score 3):

*If you want to set background color which might be not going to change, then you can use,

```
$('body').css("background-color","color-name");
```

Answer (score 3):

- If you want to change background color on button click then you can use,

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){

       $("p").css("background-color","yellow");

     }); 

   });
  ```